# Miniature receiver and transmitter for remotely controlled drone/helicopter

Tags: wireless, remote-control, drone

I am trying to search for **miniature** receiver and transmitter for custom made **drone/helicopter**.

I have no special requirements outside of a size. Sure, the size doesn't matter that much in the remote controller, but in the drone itself, it should be as small as possible so the drone can be too.

Of course, I know about all these single board computers especially made for IoT purposes like: ESP8266, Raspberry Pi (Zero), Arduino MKR with WiFi, or even MAMBA F722 MINI, but all of them seem to be too large for its purpose - to build the smallest drone possible.

I believe that people who create these RC vehicles will know about something smaller. I really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a big question, there are lots of options with various limitations,

Simple small options could include this [Seeed ARM 433Mhz RF link kit](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Seeed-Studio/113990010?qs=SElPoaY2y5Kz%252BZ3%2FqUmR2Q==&vip=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw1K75BRAEEiwAd41h1OpeZmfXlFB7eJOEZaWPZ9t6vtfjcXf5EVhagu_4X9d3KKcujwFiHBoCX7oQAvD_BwE) these are just transmitter & receivers they would need a separate microcontroller to operate them as well as some form of battery and voltage regulator.

But in depending on what you want you could also use a BT module Like the [HC-05](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-hc-05-bluetooth-module-tutorial/).

Comment: It's hard to suggest something without know more about your setup. What controller are you using? How much range do you require? What data rate will you need? What country are you in (Some countries have strict limitations of RF transmitters).  I suspect what you are asking for is a complete drone control unit like the ones discussed here? - https://oscarliang.com/flight-controller-explained/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Jack Soldano. No matter the range, baud rate, etc. I live in Czech Republic, I have never heard of these restrictions. In fact, I envision something even more miniature. It would be perfectly ideal if this drone could be about the size of a palm. When you look at today's technology, mobile phones and so on, everything is terribly miniature. But when it comes to IoT all development boards and integrated circuits are quite large.

Comment: Maybe I'll try to buy a tiny RC helicopter, because the boards in them tend to be relatively tiny, and I'll adjust it for more engines. But of course, a premade development board would be much better.